# Observable Validator does not work in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, desktop-application, community-toolkit-mvvm

I am working in wpf mvvm app, and I also use Community toolkit.mvvm also.
Here I implement Observable validator for textboxes but it does not effect on user interface,

ViewModel:

```
 public partial class UserViewModel :  ObservableValidator
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Name is Required")]
        [MinLength(3)]
        private string name= "";
    }
```

Xaml:

```
  <TextBox Text="{Binding Name,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

When I type on textbox less than 3 character and leave it It does not effect,
The TextBox accept characters in every range and also accept empty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank You! Mr. [@mm8](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7252182/mm8)

I just miss an Attribute,-->  `[NotifyDataErrorInfo]`.

Now Its working properly.

ViewModel:

```
 public partial class UserViewModel :  ObservableValidator
 {
    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyDataErrorInfo]
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Name is Required")]
    [MinLength(3, ErrorMessage ="Name Should be at least 3 character")]
    private string username;
 }
```

Xaml:

```
 <TextBox Text="{Binding Username, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Confirm that the binding is working. Setting the `ValidatesOnDataErrors` property of the binding to `true` shouldn't be necessary:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
    ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
```

Comment: I tried this too, but it didn't work.

Comment: It certainly does for me. Have you confirmed that your binding is working?

Comment: Yes, binding works properly, but validation does not work

Comment: So you don't see the default error template? Or what kind of validation are you expecting here?

Comment: I want to show an error while we leave the textbox empty or less than 3 character. Not important which kind of error, just an error if it be the form of popup it will be good

Comment: The default error template draws a red border around the `TextBox`. You should see it assuming your haven't fiddled with the style or template.

Comment: I am using Material_Design and handy_Controls in my project, I think the problem will be because of this. What should I do?

Comment: _"What should I do?"_ Perhaps try whether it would work in plain xaml without Material_Design and handy_Controls being involved

Comment: I tried your solution in a new project, but it does not work.

Comment: Thanks @mm8 I solved my problem, But now I have another problem, Here the error message does not showing. Could you help Me, I have update my Question.

Comment: @IhsanSadat: Please ask a new question if you have another issue. Don't edit the answered one.